# Javascript Addition wont work

Tags: javascript, addition

can anybody tell me how to add up these variables:

```
var preciopag = document.valores.T1.value;

var libras = document.valores.T2.value;

var serviciocom = 5.00

var contador1 = 0;

var contador2 = 0;

var tramite = 0;

var enviopty = 0;

var ITBMS = 0;

var Total = preciopag + serviciocom + enviopty + tramite + ITBMS;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly like you've done it. Could you please describe your problem? What you want your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: `preciopag` is probably coming back as a String try `parseInt(preciopag) + ....`

Comment: open the console and see what all of your variables say

Comment: Use `parseInt(x,10)` on your `document.valores...`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 3):

The `value` of elements is always a **string**, so `+` will result in *concatenation*, not addition.

Convert from string to number when retrieving the values:

```
var preciopag = +document.valores.T1.value;
var libras = +document.valores.T2.value;
```

There I've used `+`, which will look at the entire string, but you might look at `parseFloat` which will ignore anything invalid at the end; it depends entirely on what you want to do with semi-valid input.

Demonstration:

```js
var preciopag = "5";   // Simulating document.valores.T1.value
var libras = "10";     // Simulating document.valores.T2.value
var serviciocom = 5.00
var contador1 = 0;
var contador2 = 0;
var tramite = 0;
var enviopty = 0;
var ITBMS = 0;
var Total = preciopag + serviciocom + enviopty + tramite + ITBMS;

snippet.log(Total); // "55000" - wrong

// Instead:
preciopag = +"5";    // Simulating document.valores.T1.value 
libras = +"10";      // Simulating document.valores.T2.value
Total = preciopag + serviciocom + enviopty + tramite + ITBMS;

snippet.log(Total); // "10" - right
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a calculator, to know the price of shipping things to panama. here is the code https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuceivpc0jl8y7y/valida.html?dl=0  if you type 1 and 1 on the price and lb the total should be 9.22 more or less but Im getting 6.