# JavaScript unexpected NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

So I have to make some code that, when the user types a number from 1-4, it will do either + - * or /, depending on what number they choose.

```
console.log("Calculator program");                                      
console.log("1. Add numbers");
console.log("2. Subtract numbers");
console.log("3. Multiply numbers");
console.log("4. Divide numbers");

var choice = prompt ("What is your choice?");

if (choice == 1)
{
  console.log(number1 + number2);
}
if (choice == 2)
{
  console.log(number1 - number2);
}
if (choice == 3)
{
  console.log(number1 * number2);
}
if (choice == 4)
{
  console.log(number1 / number2);
}


var number1 = prompt("Type in a number"); 
var number2 = prompt("Type in another number");
```

The user is meant to put the numbers in after they have chosen a function, however when the user types in the first number, a `NaN` appears.

I assume this is because the user has not even types in the 2 numbers, but I need the user to type the numbers last.

Any help and advice would be very appreciated, thanks

Comment: Java isn't Javacript.

Comment: And strings are not numbers.

Comment: Ah wups didn't notice that, now changed.

Comment: prompt returns a string ... which is Not a Number

Comment: And ... you appear to be using number1 and number2 before you have read them.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Strings aren't numbers, but that's not why the OP is getting `NaN`.

Comment: Related, and will be the **next** problem (when you get weird results for `+`), but isn't *this* problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084975/javascript-addition-wont-work

Comment: true dat - I just read the code - some definite need for ESP in that code

Comment: Please consider approving the answer that helped you out, so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 4):

You need to accept the numbers before the if else logic and also convert those numbers either to int or float for computation (by default user prompt gets as string):

```js
console.log("Calculator program");                                      
console.log("1. Add numbers");
console.log("2. Subtract numbers");
console.log("3. Multiply numbers");
console.log("4. Divide numbers");

var number1 = prompt("Type in a number"); 
var number2 = prompt("Type in another number");
number1 = parseFloat(number1);
number2 = parseFloat(number2);
var choice = prompt ("What is your choice?");

if (choice == 1)
{
  console.log(number1 + number2);
}
if (choice == 2)
{
  console.log(number1 - number2);
}
if (choice == 3)
{
  console.log(number1 * number2);
}
if (choice == 4)
{
  console.log(number1 / number2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

assignments don't hoist so number1 and number 2 aren't defined at the time you use them

Answer (score 1):

Declare as global variable .And adding prompt before if condition .And the number was an a string output.use `parseInt()` to convert as a integer.
if you need a float use with `parseFloat()`

```js
console.log("Calculator program");                                      
console.log("1. Add numbers");
console.log("2. Subtract numbers");
console.log("3. Multiply numbers");
console.log("4. Divide numbers");
var number1=0;
var number2=0
var choice =0;
choice = parseInt(prompt ("What is your choice?"));

number1 = parseInt(prompt("Type in a number")); 
number2 = parseInt(prompt("Type in another number"));
if (choice == 1)
{
  console.log(number1 + number2);
}
if (choice == 2)
{
  console.log(number1 - number2);
}
if (choice == 3)
{
  console.log(number1 * number2);
}
if (choice == 4)
{
  console.log(number1 / number2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = function() {
console.log("Calculator program");                                      
console.log("1. Add numbers");
console.log("2. Subtract numbers");
console.log("3. Multiply numbers");
console.log("4. Divide numbers");

var choice = prompt ("What is your choice?");


var number1 = Number(prompt("Type in a number")); 
var number2 = Number(prompt("Type in another number"));

if (choice == 1)
{
  console.log(number1 + number2);
}
if (choice == 2)
{
  console.log(number1 - number2);
}
if (choice == 3)
{
  console.log(number1 * number2);
}
if (choice == 4)
{
  (number2 !== 0) && console.log(number1 / number2);
}

}
```